# How to show shape stored in attribute table from .geodatabase in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, esri-geodatabase

I have a geodatabase (filename ends with .geodatabase) and when I drag this into QGIS, I see all the tables and can browse them.

On some of those tables there attributes that *look* like they are the shapefile encoded or in a binary format or something. See this example

[image]

In the table properties, source fields, this field is defined as Type:QString TypeName: Binary.

Assuming I am correctly understanding this and it is the shapefile. How can I get QGIS to see this as a layer?

Comment: It *might* be the geometry encoded as a binary or hexadecimal string but I don't think its in "Well-known Binary" (WKB) format. Can you post a complete example as text that we can cut and paste?

Comment: Through the UI, I only see the truncated version. Is there another way to get to the full value?

Comment: I also tried to get to it through the python console and its truncated there as well.. That seems odd.

Comment: The data is in binary format... see answer and comments for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit of a longshot, but I have only seen a *.geodatabase file when working with ArcGIS. It is a Runtime Geodatabase, created from ArcMap.

When I need to consume the information stored in this type of file I use the "Copy Runtime Geodatabase to File Geodatabase" Tool in ArcMap. From the help file I see it is available in All Licenses for ArcMap, although I think it was only added to the Toolbox in ArcMap 10.3.

If you have access to ArcMap +10.3, try running the tool and then opening the *.gdb created in QGIS. You should be able to extract the features that way. Or if you have access to ArcMap, simply extract the features directly.

Comment: I used the 21 day Trial of ArcGIS Pro to achieve this as you suggested. The commands are a bit different. You use Export XML Workspace Document to convert the runtime geodatabase to XML: 
https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/export-xml-workspace-document.htm

Then use Import XML Workspace to get it into a file based gdb.
https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/import-xml-workspace-document.htm

And from there, I could drag n drop into QGIS.

Comment: One additional note.

When you are doing the Export, you need to select Storage Type : Normalized or the geometry|shapefile won't be converted to text.

Comment: Good to know, thank you. I am still coming to grips with Pro and havent explored the differences in toolsets yet. I'll keep this in mind.